# Unable to Append Dynamic Parameter in App Registration Redirect URI Azure AD

Tags: angular, azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, msal-angular

have implemented a routing with parameter in Angular Routing and declared as
`{ path: 'xyz-detail/:id', component: xyzDetailComponent, canActivate:[MsalGuard],  canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard] },`

i am using MSAL Angular Plugin and tring to add Redirect URI in Azure Ad, as `http://localhost:4200/xyx-detail/{id}` but its throwing error and i have also tried to add `*` in suffix of the url but throwing wild card error, can any one plz let me know how to add Redirect URI in Azuare AD with dynamic parameter.

Comment: Haven't used the Angular version of MSAL, but the way we have implemented this in React is that we have one page where all redirects go. Before authentication redirect we store the current path to session storage and then redirect the user there when they come back to the common redirect page.